# Trying to handle logging.error

Tags: python, logging, error-handling

Have this part of code:

```
import logging

logFormatter = logging.Formatter(u'#%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] [LINE:%(lineno)d] %(filename)-8s  %(message)s',)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

How I can handle **logging.error** calling, for example to save log in database or do something else

Comment: You mean *within* the application? You need to create and add a new handler that processes logs of that level.

Comment: You could take a look at this blog and adapt: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/logging/sqlalchemy_logger.html

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, thanks, helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest answer is to use multiple handlers, setup with different logging levels.  From the [`logging` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html), here is a perfect example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

The example provides both the `DEBUG` and `ERROR` level handler formatting for these log level types.

Perhaps another solution is to switch to using `dictConfig` for handling the python `logging` module configuration.  That would handle the structure in a `dictionary` type way, and you may be able to provide multiple values to the `level` attribute.